# Node.js emitter null data on callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, eventemitter

there is a function that I use to read all files in a directory and then sent an object with emitter to the client.

this is my code that works fine,

```
const getFilesList = (path, emitter) => {
  fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
    emitter('getFileList', files);
  });
};
```

but when I want to filter hidden files with this code, the 'standardFolders' will send empty in the emitter.

```
const getFilesList = (path, emitter) => {
  let standardFolders = [];
  fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
    if (files) {
      files.map((file) => {
        winattr.get(path + file, function (err, attrs) {
          if (err == null && attrs.directory && (!attrs.hidden && !attrs.system)) {
            standardFolders.push(file)
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      standardFolders = null;
    }
    emitter('getFileList', standardFolders);
  });
};
```

what is wrong with my code in the second part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`winattr.get(filepath,callback)` is asynchronous, so imagine your code "starts" the `file.map()` line and then immediately skips to `emitter('getFileList',standardFolders)` --- which `standardFolders` is empty because it hasn't finished yet!

You can use a library like async.io to handle your callback functions, or you can use a counter and keep track of when all of the callbacks (for each file) has finished yourself.

Example:

```js
// an asynchronous function because setTimeout
function processor(v,cb){
  let delay = Math.random()*2000+500;
  console.log('delay',delay);
  setTimeout(function(){
    console.log('val',v);
    cb(null,v);
  },delay);
  
}
const main = function(){
  const list = ['a','b','c','d'];
  let processed = [];
  let count = 0;
  console.log('starting');
  list.map(function(v,i,a){
    console.log('calling processor');
    processor(v,function(err,value){
      processed.push(v);
      count+=1;
      console.log('count',count);
      if(count>=list.length){
        // all are finished, continue on here. 
        console.log('done');
      }
    })
  })
  console.log('not done yet!');
};
main();
```

Similarly, for your code:

```
const getFilesList = (path, emitter) => {
  let standardFolders = [];
  fs.readdir(path, (err, files) => {
    if (files) {
      let count = 0;
      files.map((file) => {
        winattr.get(path + file, function (err, attrs) {
          if (err == null && attrs.directory && (!attrs.hidden && !attrs.system)) {
            standardFolders.push(file)
          }
          count+=1;
          if(count>=files.length){
            // finally done
            emitter('getFileList', standardFolders);
          }
        });
      });
    } else {
      standardFolders = null;
      emitter('getFileList', standardFolders);
    }

  });
};
```

Comment: I used both answers but none of them works! both answers return data but when I emit data to my angular component it doesn't show anything! I think something is wrong with 'winattr' callback. because when I remove that part of function it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

As already sayed in the other answer `winattr.get` is async, so the loop finishes before any of the callbacks of `winattr.get` is called.

You could convert your code using `async`/`await` and `primitify` into a code that looks almost like a sync version, and you can completely get rid of the callbacks or counters

```
const {promisify} = require('util')

const readdir = promisify(require('fs').readdir)
const winattrget = promisify(require('winattr').get)

const getFilesList = async (path, emitter) => {
  let standardFolders = [];

  try {
    let files = await readdir(path);

    for (let file of files) {
      try {
        let attrs = await winattrget(path + file)

        if (attrs.directory && (!attrs.hidden && !attrs.system)) {
          standardFolders.push(file)
        }
      } catch (err) {
        // do nothing if an error occurs
      }
    }

  } catch (err) {
    standardFolders = null;
  }

  emitter('getFileList', standardFolders);
};
```

An additional note: In your code you write `files.map`, but  mapping is use to transform the values of a given array and store them in a new one, and this is not done in your current code, so in the given case you should use a `forEach` loop instead of `map`.

Comment: I used both answers but none of them works! both answers return data but when I emit data to my angular component it doesn't show anything! I think something is wrong with 'winattr' callback. because when I remove that part of function it works fine.

Comment: @Kalagar What do you mean with `return data`, does  `standardFolders` contains entries? Because if `winattr` is the problem and causing an error the then  `standardFolders`  would be empty. If so you should check if there is an error reported at the point where ` // do nothing if an error occurs` is written, by placing `console.error(err)` there. It might  be that `path + file` is an issue if `path` does not end with a `/`, you should use `require('path').join(path, file)` anyway.

Comment: `standardFolders` contains entries. but I think `winattr` change something that angular can't handle. the data is exactly the same.

Comment: @Kalagar in the code of my answer `winattrget` does not change `file` nor `standardFolders`, so the issue has to be something else.

Comment: it is because of performance, I use `Promise` to resolve data and it runs before function end! I add a `setTimeout` to `Promise` but now it's too lazy !!